# I am getting "strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry" warning on the administer civi crm page

Tags: civicrm

I could not create any events on the CIVI CRM page, the below warning messages are getting displayed.
Could not find configure event

```
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method HTML_QuickForm_RuleRegistry::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 388.
strict warning: Non-static method CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php on line 587.
strict warning: Non-static method CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php on line 587.
strict warning: Non-static method CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateDashboardValues() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php on line 291.
strict warning: Non-static method CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php on line 587.
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following files:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php
```

Change:

```
public function singleton
public function setTemplateValues
public function setTemplateDashboardValues
```

To:

```
public static function singleton
public static function setTemplateValues
public static function setTemplateDashboardValues
```

As you can see, if you want to call a method static, it needs to have that keyword in the declaration. Insure that the keyword `$this` is not used in any of those methods as well.